# show phone storage location for VideoView

Tags: android

How to show video location from phone storage in android? I show from sd card but I try to show video from phone storage. My video location in gallery I tryed

```
vView.setVideoPath("/Gallery/test30fps.mp4");
```

but it doesn't work.

```
    //get the VideoView from the layout file
    vView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);

    //use this to get touch events
    vView.requestFocus();

    //load video from SD card
    vView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/test30fps.mp4");

    //enable this if you want to enable video controllers, such as pause and forward
    vView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    //plays the movie
    vView.start();
```

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work" - show the log please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and after Downloads write your video name `vView.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/Download/sound of birds-SD.mp4");`